# how to replace characters in string with a condition

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a string $IDN that looks like this:

`C=US, O=VeriSign, Inc., OU=VeriSign Trust Network, OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only, CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5`

I am using `preg_replace` to replace the `,` with a new line but i realised that the `,` is contained in some organization names and its chopping up the organization name.

I use this:
`$IDN = preg_replace('/, /u', "\r", $IDN);`

I am ending up with this:

```
C=US
O=VeriSign
Inc.
OU=VeriSign Trust Network
OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign
Inc. - For authorized use only
CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
```

The code does what it is suppose to but as you can see "VeriSign, Inc." is chopped up and `Inc` is moved to a new line.

Any recommendations to avoid this? I was thinking somehow to filter out `, Inc` but not sure how to go about it.

Ultimately, I want it to end up looking like this:

```
C=US
O=VeriSign, Inc.
OU=VeriSign Trust Network
OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only
CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
```

Comment: Please post a clear sample of input/output . i.e.: "i have this" and  "I need this"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list of separators 'C=', 'O=', 'OU' and 'CN'. After that just remove ', ' from end of each lines.

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strtr.php

```
<?php
$array_s = array('C=' => "\n", 'O=' => "\n", 'OU=' => "\n", 'CN=' => "\n"); // main separators
$string = "C=US, O=VeriSign, Inc., OU=VeriSign Trust Network, OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only, CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5";
echo strtr(strtr($string, $array_s), array(", \n" => "\n"));
?>
```

if you want to leave separators in output string, use this array:

```
$array_s = array('C=' => "\nC=", 'O=' => "\nO=", 'OU=' => "\nOU=", 'CN=' => "\nCN=");
```

Comment: Thats a great idea as the seperators are always the same.. any sample on how to do that ? i think this method would be most reliable.

Comment: thanks for this, i will test it out and respond shortly

Comment: i think there are some typos in your code i.e. = > should be => and 'CN' should be 'CN=' and 'OU' should be 'OU=' ? after the corrections it still was moving them to a new line. I end up with this output `C=US, O=VeriSign, Inc., OU=VeriSign Trust Network, OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only, CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5`

Comment: yeah i want to keep the separators.. ill try your latest suggestion and revert back

Answer (score 1):

You can use [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), i.e.:

```
$string = "C=US, O=VeriSign, Inc., OU=VeriSign Trust Network, OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only, CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5";
$result = preg_replace('/,\s+(?!Inc.)/', "\r", $string );
echo $result;
```

Comment: Thanks for the sample. I just saw a note from @Dioni Btter to use list of seperators - this sounds more reliable as that would cover all scenarios, not limiting to "Inc"

Comment: hasnt worked out yet.. as still need to see a working sample of that code. I will try yours out in the interim